# Which free CSS editor has most customizable options/settings for CSS code view formatting?

Tags: css, xhtml

Which free CSS editor has most customizable options/settings for CSS code view formatting?

for Windows.

Should be able to set automatic css code to any of these type of formatting.

http://css-tricks.com/different-ways-to-format-css/

Comment: what do you mean by `has most customizable options`? Could you clarify please?

Comment: Which platform? Linux? OS X? Windows?

Answer (score 1):

erm, it's CSS, its hardly the most complex of languages, its barely a language. Something like notepad++ (not the notepad built into windows btw) will be able to 'simplify' CSS. You may also find it handy to use Firefox or Chrome as you can edit bits of CSS LIVE, this means you can very quickly see if you the differences of `overflow:auto` or `overflow:scroll`for example.

Comment: notepad++ is all you need.  Apart from syntax highlighting, I find that good organization and grouping of styles is all you really need to navigate a stylesheet.  Use lots of comments, combine statements to avoid repetition, and try to keep things simple.

Comment: I find that it gives good syntax highlighting. The only time it seems to fall down, is you have a page that combines both HTML and PHP, it can't pick up on the fact you are jumping in and out of PHP